# How to modify the Zuul ServiceId at Runtime based on request param?

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

How to achieve change servciceId based on request params ??

*Below is our Zuul Config*

```
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 200000
    connection-request-timeout-millis: 200000
    socket-timeout-millis: 200000
  ignored-services: "*"
  routes:
    route-1:
      path: /path1/**
      serviceId: ServiceA
    route-2:
      path: /path2/**
      serviceId: ServiceB
```

Over here we are selecting serviceId based on path1/path2.

if http://localhost:8050/path1/endpointPath?requestParam=ParamValue1 this should call serviceA

if http://localhost:8050/path1/endpointPath?requestParam=ParamValue2 this should call serviceB

Answer (score 0):

was able to achieve this by using route filter and config changes

Config :

```
 routes:
    route-1:
      path: /**
      serviceId: ServiceA
      stripPrefix: true
```

RouteFilter:

```
 Optional<String> parameter = Optional.ofNullable(ctx.getRequest().getParameter("requestparam"));
        if (parameter.isPresent()) {
            if (parameter.get().equalsIgnoreCase("ValueA")) {
                ctx.set("serviceId", "ServiceA");

            } else {
                ctx.set("serviceId", "ServiceB");

            }
        }
```

Is this fine or do we have any simpler way to achieve ?
Here is there any we can limit not to define serviceId in properties file ?